# Appium - Received error undefined: Reference element is not defined

Tags: node.js, appium

I don't know why it's giving me this error. I have just started the automation with appium/node.js

Can anyone help me out with this?

```js
this.clickOnSavedCard.click();

const waitElemd = $('//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.uat:id/changeSelectedPayment"]');
waitElemd.waitForDisplayed(12000);

driver.touchScroll({
  el: element,
  xOffset: 10,
  yOffset: 100
});

this.runCTA.click();
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `element` (line 7 in your example code / `el: element`) is undefined. Should that be `el: waitElemd`? It's hard to say from this small sample of code.

Comment: @tex

`const pay = $('//android.widget.TextView[@resource-id="com.uat:id/changeSelectedPayment"]');
   
        driver.touchScroll({
          el: pay,
          xOffset: 10,
          yOffset: 100
        });`
**this is the error I received**.
Error: Wrong parameters applied for touchScroll
Property Description:
  "xoffset" (number): the x offset in pixels to scroll by
  "yoffset" (number): the y offset in pixels to scroll by
  "element" (string): ID of the element where the scroll starts

Comment: Try `el: 'changeSelectedPayment'` or `el: 'com.uat:id/changeSelectedPayment'`. Seems it wants the text id of the element, rather than the element, itself.

Comment: @tex 
I tried this but still facing the same issue. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using WebdriverIO and faced the problem described here: [webdriverio/issues/4172](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/issues/4172)
It really depends on the Webdriverio version you are using. According to [source code](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/a93dafc1bebf07f7bde6a3d74603beceaf851820/packages/webdriver/webdriver.d.ts#L1795) you can call it this way:

```
driver.touchScroll(10, 110, <elementId>) // current master code
```

or

```
driver.touchScroll( <elementId>, 10, 110) // webdriverio v3.4
```

Note that `elementId` is not a locator, but unique identifier that WebDriver assigns to a found element. So in order to get it, you first need to find an element with `$`.
This is why you are getting an error: the incorrect argument is passed.

Maybe you don't want to get `elementId` and later pass it to `touchScroll()`, so as doc suggested [TouchAction](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/touchAction.html) can be used instead:

```
driver.touchAction([ {action: 'press', x: startX, y: startY}, {action: 'moveTo', x: endX, y: endY}, 'release' ]);
```

where *startX,startY* and *endX,endY* are coordinates that you would like to scroll *from* and *to*

Comment: **CODE**
driver.touchScroll( 10, 110, "com.ua:id/paymentMethodTitle");


I received this error while using your above method any idea why it appear like this.. its crushing.. *ERROR*_unknown error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: invalid path  _

Comment: "com.ua:id/paymentMethodTitle" is locator you use to find element, but you need to have elementId: it is a unique identifier WebDriver assign to every element that been found during the session. As I said, you better not use touchScroll. Please check TouchAction

Comment: Yup TouchAction is working for me. 
** Code**  driver.touchAction([
          {action: 'press', x: 782, y: 1332},
          {action: 'moveTo', x: 773, y: 765},
          'release'
        ]);